# Custom layout in Options Menu Item is showing empty layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Why custom layout is not getting displayed in options menu item?  [image]

Some of the posts mentioned use app namespace instead of android namespace and showAsAction should be "always". Tried with all combinations but no Luck.

Its always showing blank layout.

below is my code

This is menu layout

```
<?

xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.dms.hanumanchalisa.activities.MainActivity">

        <item android:id="@+id/menu_group"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        app:showAsAction="always">

            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_set_alarm"
                    app:showAsAction="always"
                    app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_alarm"
                    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />

                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_adjust"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
                    android:title="@string/adjust_string"
                    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
                    android:title="@string/delete_string"
                    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_about"
                    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
                    android:title="@string/about_string"
                    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
            </menu>
            </item>

</menu>
```

custom layout used in menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startSetDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set Target Time" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/btnalarm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="@string/string_alarm_off"
        android:textOn="@string/string_alarm_on" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code used in activity to display options menu

```
 @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    optionsMenu = menu;
    MenuItem groupItem = optionsMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_group);
    MenuItem alarmMenuItem = (MenuItem) groupItem.getSubMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_set_alarm);
    btnSelectTime = (Button) alarmMenuItem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.startSetDialog);
    alarmSetCheckbox = (CheckBox) alarmMenuItem.getActionView().findViewById(R.id.btnalarm);
    btnSelectTime.setOnClickListener(this);
    alarmSetCheckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    if (isPrayerExsists) {
        groupItem.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        groupItem.setVisible(false);
    }
    return true;
```

setOnclicklistener is also not throwing any error means views in custom layout are not null.

TIA

Comment: is it possible it needs some sort of separate inflating, as you would do with a common layout for e.g. `activity` or `fragment`?